# Laravel BelongsTo confusion

Tags: laravel, relationship, laravel-blade, belongs-to

I have an OneToMany relation between EVENT and MAJOR model as following's schema :

EVENT belongs to Major and Major HasMany Events

Here is my tables in MySQl

```
EVENTS Table :

   id   name          major_id  
    1   liga 1st          1     
    2   liga 2nd          2     

Majors Table :

id  symbol                 name     
1   MTB           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  
2   ROAD          yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy  
3   TRACK         zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
```

in controller I passed all event's data to the view as following:

```
 $events= Event::all();
```

and in my view I could not reach majors table based on relation :

```
   @foreach($events as $event)
     <option value="">{{$event->major->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
```

But I tried with this code and it works :

```
   @foreach($data as $event)
    <option value="">{{$event->major()->first()->name }}</option>
   @endforeach
```

my question is if each event have one Major_id why shouldn't I utilize the first query that I noted above.

Comment: Welcome to SO .. as per your relationship everything is correct . i think you need to add belongsTo in `Event.php`

Comment: can we see the relationships on the models?

Comment: I've already done as followings:
 public function major()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Major::class);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 24H I finally found the ridicules problem !

I'd assigned a **getMajorAttribute**() in my model and it was processing the output data ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried once again in my controller

```
$data = Event::find(1);
return $data->major;
```

I fetched an event but I could not access to its major object !!!
It returns Null
confused !